# Program to fetch a set of rows in PHP has the same code structure, but no results on the other one

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement

Good day. So I have a program that will fetch a set of rows from MySql depending on the select option that I clicked in a select option in HTML and display it into a container in HTML. The code works on the first one, but somehow on the 2nd one it does not fetch the rows I requested. I already checked if the column names are correct and if the value for the select option matches the "if statement" in my PHP code.

In the first snippet of codes, it works properly,

```
if($_POST["FilterDoc"]=="document_type")
        {
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY document_type ASC");
        $data = "";
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $document_type = $rows['document_type'];
            $date_received = $rows['date_received'];
            $application_no = $rows['application_no'];
            $hei = $rows['hei'];
            $school_name = $rows['school_name'];
            $from_co = $rows['from_co'];
            $other_govt = $rows['other_govt'];
            $contact_person = $rows['contact_person'];
            $comment = $rows['comment'];
            $program = $rows['program'];
            $year_level = $rows['year_level'];
            $academic_year = $rows['academic_year'];
            $transaction_no = $rows['transaction_no'];

            $output =  "<table><tr><td>$document_type</td><td>$date_received</td><td>$application_no</td><td>$hei</td><td>$school_name</td><td>$from_co</td><td>$other_govt</td><td>$contact_person</td><td>$comment</td><td>$program</td><td>$year_level</td><td>$academic_year</td><td>$transaction_no</td></tr></table><br>";
           $data .=  '<a href = "editdoc.php?v='.$transaction_no.'" name="documents">'.$output.'</a>';
          }
        echo $data ;

        }
```

But on the 2nd code even though it has the same code structure, doesn't work as I'd hoped to be,

```
else if($_POST["FilterDoc"]=="other")
        {

        $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY other_govt ASC");
        while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $data = "";
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $document_type = $rows['document_type'];
            $date_received = $rows['date_received'];
            $application_no = $rows['application_no'];
            $hei = $rows['hei'];
            $school_name = $rows['school_name'];
            $from_co = $rows['from_co'];
            $other_govt = $rows['other_govt'];
            $contact_person = $rows['contact_person'];
            $comment = $rows['comment'];
            $program = $rows['program'];
            $year_level = $rows['year_level'];
            $academic_year = $rows['academic_year'];
            $transaction_no = $rows['transaction_no'];

            $output =  "<table><tr><td>$other_govt</td><td>$document_type</td><td>$date_received</td><td>$application_no </td><td>$hei</td><td>$school_name</td><td>$from_co</td><td>$contact_person</td><td>$comment</td><td>$program</td><td>$year_level</td><td>$academic_year</td><td>$transaction_no</td></tr></table><br>";
           $data .=  '<a href = "editdoc.php?v='.$transaction_no.'" name="documents">'.$output.'</a>';
          }
        echo $data;             
        }
```

Here's the HTML code for my select option,

```
<select name = "FilterDoc" onchange = "filterby(this);">
      <option selected disabled>Filter By</option>
      <option value="document_type">Document Type</option>
      <option value="date">Date</option>
      <option value="hei">HEI</option>
      <option value="other">Other Govt.</option>
      <option value="person">Person</option></select>
```

The column name from my database which is *other_govt* isn't the primary key and has duplicate values. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the query `SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY other_govt ASC` from the MySQL CLI or PHPMyAdmin to make sure it works. Check the error codes from `mysqli_query()`.

This loop is removing all of your result rows silently:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $data = "";
```

So that's an error.

You may find it easier to use the `extract()` function to pull all of the `$row` values into local variables. Or use `mysqli_fetch_ojbect($result)` and then use `...<td>{$rows->document}</td>...` to generate the output.

Also usually a good idea to escape strings you output to HTML with `htmlspecialchars()`. Assuming associative array:

Your code will generate a table for every row, probably not want you want. Put the `<table>` tags outside of the loop, the `<tr>` inside the loop for each row, then you can iterate over the column values:

```
foreach ($rows as $col => $val) {
    $output .= '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($val).'</td>';
}
```

You can get the columns in the desired order for the table by specifying them in the `SELECT` instead of using `SELECT *`.

Comment: Oh! I clearly didnțt notice that. My frustration got ahead of me. Thank you sir!

Comment: But may I ask also what is $rows, $col, and $val based on my code? I got confused a bit.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns an associative array of `[column => value, column => value, ...]` each time you call it, until it has retrieved all rows from the database driver.

You can iterate over an associative array with `foreach ($rows as $col => $val) { ... }` which will put the column name in `$col` and the value in `$val` for each `column => value` pair in the row data.

Answer (score 0):

All your functional codes are looking fine. But, You have called

`while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` in the second code.

I think **mysql_fetch_assoc** can't be called twice.

Remove that unwanted line and check it.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra line of code just right after your query:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$mQuery = "";
$Filter = $_POST["FilterDoc"];switch ($Filter) {
 case "document_type":
       $mQuery = "your query for document type";
     break; case "other":
$mQuery = "your query for other type";
break; }            if (!empty($mQuery)) { {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $mQuery);
    $data = "";
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $document_type = $rows['document_type'];
        $date_received = $rows['date_received'];
        $application_no = $rows['application_no'];
        $hei = $rows['hei'];
        $school_name = $rows['school_name'];
        $from_co = $rows['from_co'];
        $other_govt = $rows['other_govt'];
        $contact_person = $rows['contact_person'];
        $comment = $rows['comment'];
        $program = $rows['program'];
        $year_level = $rows['year_level'];
        $academic_year = $rows['academic_year'];
        $transaction_no = $rows['transaction_no'];
        $output = "<table><tr><td>$document_type</td><td>$date_received</td><td>$application_no</td><td>$hei</td><td>$school_name</td><td>$from_co</td><td>$other_govt</td><td>$contact_person</td><td>$comment</td><td>$program</td><td>$year_level</td><td>$academic_year</td><td>$transaction_no</td></tr></table><br />";
        $data.= '<a href = "editdoc.php?v=' . $transaction_no . '" name="documents">' . $output . '</a>';
    }

    echo $data;
}
else {
    echo "Unknown Filter Request";
}
```